# Proper way to wait for a lambda to complete

Tags: java

I came across the following snippet of code:

```
AmqpConnection connection;
AmqpClient client = AmqpClient.create(someOptions);

client.connect(ar -> {
  if (ar.failed()) {
    System.out.println("Connection failed.");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Connection succeeded");
    connection = ar.result();
  }
});

// Wait for connection to succeed before moving on...
connection.doSomething() //etc...
```

I would like to use it but there needs to be a blocking mechanism so connection is not null.  I do not want to move connection.doSomething() inside the lambda.
What is the proper way to block in that scenario? A while loop with a timer?  A Future/Callable? Something else?

Comment: Using a Future is probably desirable here.

Comment: Just a small pedantic thing here: A lambda function is just a function. The lambda function may be executed synchronously or asynchronously. It's up to the caller to define the behaviour (it's just like calling a method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Future is one great way, however does `connect` return one?

You said you prefer not to, but another option would be to add it all to the lambda itself - if you're waiting anyway, why not do it together?

I think the way you have it set now is not a good one, as lambdas are not supposed to affect variables outside their body (I believe you'll receive a compile error on this).

There are some more ways using `java.util.concurrent`, but I think these 2 are the best.

---

**EDIT**

Following discussion in the comments, and clarification that the connection is thread safe, you can split to `ConnectionUtil` that creates the connection (once-only), and `ConnectionUsage` as a usage example:

```
public class ConnectionUtil {

    private static AmqpConnection connection;

    private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static AmqpConnection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            lock.lock();
            if (connection == null) {
                AmqpClient client = AmqpClient.create(someOptions);
                client.connect(ar -> {
                    if (ar.failed()) {
                        System.out.println("Connection failed.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Connection succeeded");
                        connection = ar.result();
                    }
                });
            }
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    public static <T> T doWithConnection(Function<AmqpConnection, T> function) {
        return function.apply(getConnection());
    }
}
```

For usage, you have 2 options - if it is okay to pass the `AmqpConnection` around, you can call `getConnection`, and if not have your lambda ready and pass it to `doWithConnection`:

```
public class ConnectionUsage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you can get the connection and do stuff
        AmqpConnection connection = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();


        // you can call the util and let him do stuff
        Function<AmqpConnection, Void> func = amqpConnection -> {
            // do stuff
            return null;
        };
        ConnectionUtil.doWithConnection(func);
    }
}
```

Comment: connect does not return one :(  I would prefer to not move it inside the lambda, because many different classes may use identical connection setup code (and there would be more complex code within that, not shown here). It would be easier to initialize the connection in one place, then do their separate things once the connection is established.

Comment: You can have all those classes implement a `Consumer<AmqpConnection>`, and pass them to your initialiser, and have him call them after completion.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I'm not following :(

Comment: Say you have a class `ConnectionInitializer` with method `doWithConnection(Consumer<AmqpConnection> consumer)`. In that class, you initialize your connection in the lambda, and then (still in the lambda) call `consumer.accept(connection)`. This way initialization code is common, and usage can differ.

Comment: If the code were written that way what would happen if multiple calls were made using that connection?  Would a new one be initialized every time the connection object needed to be used? If so, that would not work in my situation.

Comment: You can initialize a connection only once using a singleton pattern, and pass it to every caller

Comment: So I guess I'm asking the best way to do that since the connection is inside the lambda

Comment: added an example for thread-safe initialization, and using the same connection in multiple places